# skipped and fakestop remove from leaflet 1.8

Tags: path, leaflet, transform

skipped and fakestop remove from DomEvent in leaflet!pathtransfrom use both methods
what is the alternative to skipped?fakestop?!

pathtransform: github w8r/Leaflet.Path.Transform